# Angular Cannot read property 'countryId',stateId,cityName etc of null

Tags: javascript, angular

How to make changes in code to avoid null error? Please help. I want to remove `cannot read property of null` error for all variables `countryId,stateId` and all things in the code. How to provide null checks for the code?

```
location: {
    countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
    ? this.requestType === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE'
        ? parseInt(this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, 10)
        : this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
    : null,
    stateId: this.supplierData.stateIdForAddress ? 
    this.supplierData.stateIdForAddress : null,
    stateName: this.supplierData.stateNameForAddress ? 
    this.supplierData.stateNameForAddress : null,
    cityName: this.supplierData.cityNameForAddress ? 
    this.supplierData.cityNameForAddress : null,
    provinceName: this.requestAddresses[index].location.provinceName
    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.provinceName
    : null,
    postalCode: this.supplierData.postalCodeForAddress
    ? this.supplierData.postalCodeForAddress
    : null,
    addressLine1: this.supplierData.addressLine1ForAddress
    ? this.supplierData.addressLine1ForAddress
    : null,
    addressLine2: this.supplierData.addressLine2ForAddress
    ? this.supplierData.addressLine2ForAddress
    : null,
    addressLine3: this.supplierData.addressLine3ForAddress
    ? this.supplierData.addressLine3ForAddress
    : null,
    addressLine4: this.supplierData.addressLine4ForAddress
    ? this.supplierData.addressLine4ForAddress
    : null,
    poBoxNumber: this.requestAddresses[index].location.poBoxNumber
    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.poBoxNumber
    : null,
    internalId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.internalId
    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.internalId
    : null,
    },
    };
    addressesEntity.push(tempObj);
});
```

Comment: What says console.log(this.requestAddresses) ?

Comment: Hi Beller i will check and show you

Comment: Hi Kai how to refactor to do null check at a time

Comment: for this one how to write

Comment: countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                        ? this.requestType === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE'
                          ? parseInt(this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, 10)
                          : this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                        : null,

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

`Use such if condition on each variable`

```
if(!countryId){
  console.log('countryId is either null or undefined');
}
```

**Method 2**

`please use try catch statement in such cases, All the programmatical errors in this case will fall in catch.`

```
try{
}catch(err) {
}
```

Comment: What this line means ? 
countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId ? this.requestType === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE' ? parseInt(this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, 10) : this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId : null,

Comment: like how many conditions are you implementing here ? you are using ternary operator, but syntax is complete wrong, you are using continuous ? ? ? and : : at the end, how are you handling if elseif elseif condition in this line

Comment: for this one countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                    ? this.requestType === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE'
                      ? parseInt(this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, 10)
                      : this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                    : null,